# Can PHP send json data back to calling script then resume processing like flush()?

Tags: php, jquery

jQuery

```
var result='';
jQuery.ajax
({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: <?php  echo '"' .plugins_url('/test.php', __FILE__); ?>?Query="+ jQuery('#test').val(),
    success: function(data)
    {   
        //process results
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(arguments);
        alert('HTTP Error: '+errorThrown+' | Error Message: '+textStatus);
        return;
    }

});
```

test.php

```
$file = $rootPath.'wp-content/uploads/test/'.$query.".txt";

if (file_exists($seoCacheFile) && is_readable($seoCacheFile))
{
    $retarr = file_get_contents($file);
    if($retarr !=="")
    {
        print_r($retarr);die;
    }
}


if(count($ret)){
    $retarr = json_encode(array('response' => array('test' => array('Results'=>$ret))));
    print_r($retarr);
    flush();

    //PROBLEM IS HERE
    //If an error occurs here, the json is mangled, flush() does not help. Can I send the json and deal with PHP errors separately?
    /*  if (!is_dir($rootPath.'wp-content/uploads/test/')){mkdir($rootPath.'wp-content/uploads/test/');}
        $seoCacheFile = fopen($rootPath.'wp-content/uploads/test/'.$query.".txt",'w');
        fwrite($File, $retarr);fclose($File);
    */
}
```

Or do I need to move the write operation out of the php and create a second ajax call, passing the json to it?

Comment: What does the mangled output look like?  You should be able to do both in a single request, so long as the rest of your code doesn't output anything (i.e. suppress any other errors, or do the writing to file first and send an error notice in your JSON if a problem occurs).

Comment: The output is perfect json data, then ends with the PHP error message, which throws everything off in the calling script.

Comment: Well, you can set display errors to be disabled, but you should probably just fix the error so that it's not mangling your output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display from being displayed with `ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');` at the top of your script. You should then log all errors by putting this at the top:

```
ini_set('log_errors','On');
ini_set('error_log','path-to-phperror-log.log');
```

You then need to handle the possible error in your code, sending back the appropriate information if an error is encountered. For example:

```
json_encode(array('result' => 'error', 'error' => 'File I/O error.'));
```

Also, make sure `$query` is escaped properly. You don't want someone passing in a path like `../../../wp-login.php`.

Comment: `print_r()`ing the string will work, because for a string it just prints the string.  It is a strange way to do things.